# PHP PDO Prepare select where ? Query Error

Tags: php, pdo, where-clause

```
   public function listeFilitreAltKategoriId($filitre,$limit,$offset) {
    $sorgu = self::$db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM urun WHERE (?) LIMIT ?,?" );
    $sorgu->execute(array($filitre,$limit,$offset));
    return $sorgu;
  }


    $limit=0;
$offset=10;
       $strSemt= implode(',',$semt);
       $where=[];
      $where[]="altkategoriid={$sorguAltMenu[ 'id' ]}";
      if($strSemt!=""){
       $where[]="semt IN ($strSemt)";
      }  
      if(!empty($min) || !empty($max)){
        if(!empty($min) && empty($max)){
         $where[]="fiyat >= $min ";
       }
        if(!empty($max) && empty($min)){
         $where[]="fiyat <= $max";
       }
         if(!empty($max) && !empty($min)){
         $where[]="fiyat BETWEEN $min AND $max";
       }
       
  }
  if($kur!=""){
   $where[]="kur=$kur";
  }
  $filitre = implode(" AND ",$where);
 $UrunList = ( new UrunModel() )->listeFilitreAltKategoriId($filitre,$limit,$offset);
```

I Use Similar to This And The Result Freezes To Zero.
This Is The Way The Query Works.
But I Wanna Make It Work Like The Master.
I know you have received a question similar to this, but I haven't solved it for 2 hours.

```
//$db=(new UrunModel())->database();
   // $UrunList = $db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM  urun WHERE  ".implode(" AND ",$where)." LIMIT $limit,$offset" );
   // $UrunList->execute();
```

Comment: You cannot bind a whole WHERE clause, you cannot even bind column or table names. You would have to add the WHERE clause in as part of the SQL string.

Comment: $filitre Adding with your variable? Where the sign is

Comment: How Do I Edit the Top Query In This Case?

Comment: public function listeFilitreAltKategoriId($filitre,$limit,$offset) {
    $sorgu = self::$db->prepare( "SELECT * FROM urun WHERE $filitre LIMIT $limit,$offset" );
    $sorgu->execute();
    return $sorgu;
  } Was There A Strange Solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = [
    "min_limit" => $min,
    "max_limit" => $max
];

$where[]     = "altkategoriid = :id";
$value["id"] = $sorguAltMenu['id'];


if( !empty($min) && empty($max) ){
    $where[]      = "fiyat >= :min";
    $value["min"] = $min;
}
if( !empty($max) && empty($min) ){
    $where[]      = "fiyat <= :max";
    $value["max"] = $max;
}
if( !empty($max) && !empty($min) ){
    $where[]      = "fiyat BETWEEN :min AND :max";
    $value["min"] = $min;
    $value["max"] = $max;
}

if( !empty($kur) ){
    $where[]      = "kur = :kur";
    $value["kur"] = $kur;
}

if( count($semt) ){
    $place_holders = [];
    $count         = 1;
    foreach($semt as $semt_value){
        $place_holders[]          = ":semt_{$count}";
        $value["semt_{$count++}"] = $semt_value;
    }
    $place_holder_string = implode(", ", $place_holders);
    $where[]             = "semt IN ({$place_holder_string})";
}  

$where_clause = implode(" AND ", $where);

$sql = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM urun  
    WHERE {$where_clause}
    LIMIT :min_limit, :max_limit
";

$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($value);

while( $row = $query->fetchObject() ){
    // Do something...
}
```